# Model Generation using sequelize with MySQL dialect

Tags: mysql, database-design, sequelize.js, constraints, auto-increment

Queries Regarding Model Generation using sequelize:

1. How to provide auto-increment custom value in sequelize using MySQL.
2. How can I set the current timestamp to any field as a datatype. (Current implementation shown in query didn't work for me!)
3. How to set ROW_FORMAT = COMPACT?
4. How to customize constraint name in Unique Key or Foreign Key?

Which changes required? and in which file Model OR Migration.

What I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbltests` (
  `testId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nameId` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `nameunique` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `timet` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nameunique` (`nameunique`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

What I want as output:

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbltests` (
      `testId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nameId` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
      `nameunique` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `timet` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
      `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`testId`),
      UNIQUE KEY `nameunique` (`nameunique`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Comment: Typo in the PK for tbltests.

Comment: This is not clear. What is your problem? If you want the latter why aren't you using it? What is your actual code? [mre] PS There is no column notificationId in either create so how can it be PK? PS Ask 1 specific non-duplicate question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions Regarding Model Generation using sequelize:

> How to provide auto-increment custom value in sequelize using MySQL?

As shown in **CreateTable** query in asked question, AUTO_INCREMENT simply refers to its own records count i.e., if we have 2 records the query statement will show that count as **AUTO_INCREMENT = 2**

> How to customize constraint name in Unique Key or Foreign Key?

Using **addConstraint()** function we can add constraints for Foreign Key and unique key as well with custom constraint name too. Shown snippet for Foreign Key:

```
return queryInterface.addConstraint(
'Tabletests',
['GeneratedBy'],
  {
    type: 'foreign key',
    name: 'GeneratedBy_FK_1',
    references: {
      table: 'TableUsers',
      field: 'Uid'
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
  }
);
```